# Joomla! (with K2) MySql - Error when generating

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-k2

I dont get it ... I tested a lot but dont get why a SQL error appears ...

In my case I use a function to generate a mysql-query to get all extra-field items from the database (K2 - Component).

It is used like this:

```
public static function readExtraFields ($fields, $as = 'array') {
        if (!is_array($fields)) $fields = json_decode($fields);
        $result = array();

        $whereId = array();
        $allFieldValues = array();
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $whereId[] = "`id`='".$field->id."'";
            $allFieldValues[$field->id] = $field->value;
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `#__k2_extra_fields` WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $whereId);

        $queryResult = self::execQuery($query);
        [...]
```

In this method a query will be generated like this (I printed it out)

```
SELECT * FROM `#__k2_extra_fields` WHERE `id`='1' OR `id`='2'
```

This is fine. When I execute the methode execQuery with the given query this error appears:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 SQL=SELECT * FROM `j7req_k2_extra_fields` WHERE
```

Thats all ... I dont get it. My method to execute my mysql-query:

```
public static function execQuery ($query) {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadObjectList();
        return $result;
    }
```

For testing I printed out the Query (the above) and set $query to the printed query and this runs without any problems like the way it should work ... So the query which is given is right ... what can be the problem ?

**Edit 1**
In my execQuery method I printed the $db out. This reuslt is given (you can find the query at the bottom of this object)

```
JDatabaseDriverMysqli Object
(
    [name] => mysqli
    [nameQuote:protected] => `
    [nullDate:protected] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [_database:JDatabaseDriver:private] => podopraxis
    [connection:protected] => mysqli Object
        (
            [affected_rows] => 1
            [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
            [client_version] => 50011
            [connect_errno] => 0
            [connect_error] => 
            [errno] => 0
            [error] => 
            [error_list] => Array
                (
                )

            [field_count] => 1
            [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP
            [info] => 
            [insert_id] => 0
            [server_info] => 5.6.16
            [server_version] => 50616
            [stat] => Uptime: 48979  Threads: 1  Questions: 6461  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 163  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 155  Queries per second avg: 0.131
            [sqlstate] => 00000
            [protocol_version] => 10
            [thread_id] => 203
            [warning_count] => 0
        )

    [count:protected] => 45
    [cursor:protected] => 
    [debug:protected] => 
    [limit:protected] => 0
    [log:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [callStacks:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [offset:protected] => 0
    [options:protected] => Array
        (
            [driver] => mysqli
            [host] => localhost
            [user] => root
            [password] => 
            [database] => podopraxis
            [prefix] => j7req_
            [select] => 1
            [port] => 3306
            [socket] => 
        )

    [sql:protected] => SELECT * FROM `#__k2_extra_fields` WHERE `id`='1' OR `id`='2'
    [tablePrefix:protected] => j7req_
    [utf:protected] => 1
    [errorNum:protected] => 0
    [errorMsg:protected] => 
    [transactionDepth:protected] => 0
    [disconnectHandlers:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query fired in execQuery() function is missing the condition statement after "WHERE" clause of query.

Please make sure below part of condition comes in your query:

```
`id`='1' OR `id`='2'
```

let me know if I am not getting well about your question?

Also try to post here whole $db object by printing as below:

```
 echo "<pre />";print_r($db);exit;
```

Comment: Take a look to my Edit 1 in my Post. There i posted the result of $db when I generate my query.

Comment: As long as I can see that there is not issue with your code and query since I have tried it to my k2 site and its absolutely working.

Can you please get me the MySQL version that you used ?

Comment: Thats the fun fact .. in the office this code work also ... just on my private PC the code doesnt .. seems to be a php or mysql ini probmlen. I have the sane version of php and mysql so I have to check the settings ...

Comment: yeah, it looks like something is wrong with your MySQL module. can you please try to install new MySQL after removing current version ?

Comment: I am not at home now but I will try this later this day.

Comment: I can not recognize the problem but reinstall my XAMPP installation helped me out ...

Comment: Yeah.. As always it was mysterious bug from MySQL modules.